# MySql - multiple nested AND clauses

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get results from the below query in which I have two AND clauses nested based on this table:

```
+------+------+--------------+ 
| s_id | q_id | value_text   |
+------+------+--------------+
|  3   |  8   | BANK00236656 |
|  4   | 10   | f5fsd0236656 |
|  5   | 14   | 87749854     |
+------+------+--------------+
```

The below WHERE clause does not yield any results even though it should output "3" and "5".

```
WHERE 1 
AND 
(custom_field_values.q_id = '8' AND custom_field_values.value_text = 'BANK00236656') 
AND 
(custom_field_values.q_id = '14' AND custom_field_values.value_text = '87749854')
ORDER BY evaluation_complete.eval_score DESC
```

When I change the second AND to OR (the one linking the two clauses between parenthesis) the query does output the correct result.

Any suggestions on how to link multiple AND clauses that should be true?

Thanks!

Comment: No that should be an `OR`...

Comment: `WHERE (condition and condition and condition.....) OR (condition and condition and condition.....)`

Comment: Thanks but I need to figure out how to link them with an AND statement.

Comment: @Mousse: I think you interpret the AND  too much as a natural language operator. One can indeed say "I want coffee and cookies". But if you query a database, you say "I want everything where the type is coffee or cookies".

Comment: You want an OR. Then, for further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

An `AND` operator is `TRUE` given its two *operands* are `TRUE`. Now for your clause that can *never* happen, since a column `q_id` ca not be `8` and `14` at the same time.

What you need is an `OR` operator. An `OR` operator is `TRUE` if at least one of its operands is `TRUE`.

So that should be:

```
WHERE (custom_field_values.q_id = '8' AND custom_field_values.value_text = 'BANK00236656') 
OR    (custom_field_values.q_id = '14' AND custom_field_values.value_text = '87749854')
ORDER BY evaluation_complete.eval_score DESC
```

Note that the individual conditions (between the brackets) still use an `AND` operator, since both conditions should be satisfied.